# Stubborn WinForm loses focus and doesn't regain it

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, drag-and-drop, focus

I have a form with a splitview container. The left side is a devex GridView and the right side is just a regular view. I drag-drop text from the `GridView` to the view at the right hand side. To simulate drag-drop I use `MouseDown` event of the `GridView` combined with `DoDragDrop` and `DragOver` methods of the view on the right hand side.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that after I drag and drop the data from the GridView, I first need to do a click (anywhere on the screen) before I can click anywhere else on the *entire* form. I tried, `Focus` , `Activate`, `TopMost` methods for both views but for some reason they don't seem to work; forcing me to click once before I am able to click somewhere else on the entire form.

I know this is a pretty vague quetion but any ideas how I can solve this ?